# TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" truncates entire string

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, texttrimming

I have defined a style resource for TexBlock control. Where I am trying to assign it's TextTrimming property as "WordEllipsis". The problem is that the outcome is a blank text instead of some string with some dots.

Here is my style resource:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource ContactStatusToColorConvertor}}" BorderThickness="7" CornerRadius="90">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource StringToAssetUrlConverter}}" Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="60,53" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" />
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>
        </Border>
        <!--<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30">-->
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" Height="30">
            <TextBlock Text="A very loong name" Style="{StaticResource AWTextBlockNormalStyle}" Height="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
        </Border>
        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="3,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource AWTextBlockNormalStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />-->
        <!--</StackPanel>-->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate> ##
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is working:

```
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="2" Height="50">
        <TextBlock Text="A very loong name" Height="30" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="100"/>
    </Border>
```

as You are giving same `height` for `border` and `Textblock` its not showing the text.

Comment: Tried this, not working for me. Actually problem is not because of the border. I just added it to see if the texblock is getting rendered at all (by providing the thickness as 2).

Comment: i have implemented above code, just added width of textblock n height of border more than textblock. its working.

Comment: May be it's because I have set the datatemplate and using this resource for my LongListSelector control. When I simply add a control like you said, it works fine.